# Word or phrase meaning "working hours have ended, and it's time to go home"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What word or phrase is used to signify that the work day has ended?

Answer (score 13):

If you *call it a day*, it means that you consider the day's work is done.

Answer (score 3):

They may say that they are going to ["call it quits"](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/call+it+quits):

> to quit; to resign from something; to announce that one is quitting.
>
> Okay! I've had enough! I'm calling it quits.
>
> Time to go home, John. Let's call it quits.

In this sense, *quit* is not used to mean that they are leaving their job for good but that they are leaving for the night. A related phrase is "quitting time":

> Ok, 5pm. It's quitting time. I'm going home.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest thing is:

> **Home time!**

Comment: Do people really say that? I've never heard it before.

Comment: Very common in the UK.

Answer (score 1):

It's correct to say

> I'm off

optionally with "See ya tomorrow (or next week)"

Answer (score 1):

When the day has ended, you usually say "It's nighttime" :)

When you are stopping your work, you say "I'm calling it a day"

Answer (score 0):

"It's Miller Time!" in reference to old advertisements for Miller beer.

Answer (score 0):

> [Closing time](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xGytDsqkQY8)
>   "One last call for alcohol ... you don't have to go home, but you can't stay here."

Answer (score 0):

How about "knocking-off time"? [Collins English Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/knocking-off-time)

Answer (score 0):

I work in IT industry. I normally say "Signing off..."

When I was in a German project we used to say *"Feierabend"*, but thats not relevant here as its a German word.